# this inside simple function returning arrow function

Tags: javascript

Why the arrow function returned in the following example doesn't prints undefined

```js
let obj = {
  a: "88",
  c: () => {
    console.log(this.a);
  },
  d: function() {
    return () => {
      console.log(this.a);
    }

  }
}

let ob = {
  a: 99
}


let t = obj.d()
t(); // its printing 88 not undefined why
```

Answer (score 2):

`d` was created with a function expression

Therefore when you call `obj.d()` the value of `this` is the same as the value of `obj`.

`d` returns an arrow function.

Arrow functions have lexical `this` so it uses `this` from `d` which was the same as `obj`

`this.a` is therefore the same as `obj.a` which is `"88"`

Answer (score 0):

Because when you do `let t = obj.d()`, it will return you a function that will be saved in `t`

```
    t = () => {
      console.log(this.a);
    }
```

Now talking about `this.a`, here `this` will the `obj` and value of `a` in `obj` is `88` do that is the reason `88` is printed